# How to find voxels intersected with a cone?

Tags: convex-cone

I have a 3D cube with 128x128x128 voxels. A cone is passing through this 3D cube. How can I find which voxels of cube are inside cone?[image]

Comment: Voxel? ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: 3D cube is subdivided into small cubes called voxel similar to like pixels of an image